# How to loop through last.fm results with getJSON

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, each, last.fm

I'm new to JS and trying to get my last.fm `toptracks` over the last 7 days with a limit of 3 from their API here:

http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=thisisheroic&period=7day&limit=3&api_key=3cbc1a3aa903935d08223263bcc3ba0b&format=json

Here's my code below which works but whenever I change the `limit` to more than `1`, it fails with no console error. Any idea how I can use `.html` to print out an array of those 3 track names?

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=thisisheroic&period=7day&limit=1&api_key=3cbc1a3aa903935d08223263bcc3ba0b&format=json", function(result){
    $.each(result, function(){
        $('#lastfm_toptracks').html(result.toptracks.track.name);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, you need to amend your code to loop over the returned `result.toptracks.track` array. Secondly, you need to change `html()` to `append()`, otherwise you are overwriting the text of the element on every iteration and will only see the final track. Try this:

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=thisisheroic&period=7day&limit=3&api_key=3cbc1a3aa903935d08223263bcc3ba0b&format=json", function(result){
    $.each(result.toptracks.track, function(i, track){
        $('#lastfm_toptracks').append('<p>' + track.name + '</p>');
    });
});
```

[**Example fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/kuwnnydu/)

Also, note that the [documentation](http://www.last.fm/api/show/user.getTopTracks) states that the default setting for `limit` is 50 per request.

Answer (score 0):

Below the the code:

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=thisisheroic&period=7day&limit=3&api_key=3cbc1a3aa903935d08223263bcc3ba0b&format=json", function(result){        
    $.each(result.toptracks.track, function(key, val){        
        console.log(val.name);
        $('#lastfm_toptracks').append('<div>'+ val.name + '</div>');
    });
});
```

And the fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/k6g6v0rc/1/

Answer (score 0):

This is just a Syntax error

```
$.getJSON("http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=user.gettoptracks&user=thisisheroic&period=7day&limit=3&api_key=3cbc1a3aa903935d08223263bcc3ba0b&format=json", function(results){
console.log(results);
$.each(results.toptracks.track, function(index,value){
    //$('#lastfm_toptracks').html(result.toptracks.track.name);
    alert(value.name);
});
```

});

Should be working.

The link is to a working demo.

http://jsfiddle.net/nnyf0n28/7/

Please explore more on this link:: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/